# Why does adding user to docker user group allows docker to be run as non root?

Tags: docker

Docker needs root permissions to run. [This](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user) guide gives instructions about managing docker as a non-root user, it essentially adds the user to `docker` user group after which I'm able to run docker commands without `sudo`. Can someone explain why does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to distinguish between the docker command line tool `docker` and the background daemon `dockerd`. The daemon runs as root and is responsible for running containers. The command line tool `docker` gives the daemon instructions, what to do. This communication is done via the unix socket `/var/run/docker.sock` by default. An `ls -l` yields

```
srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Aug 20 11:22 /var/run/docker.sock
```

You can see that a user which belongs to the group `docker` is able to write to the socket and thus is able to give the daemon instructions which can be executed with root permission.

You can also [configure](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-socket-option) the daemon to listen on a network port instead. Similarly you can [tell](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#description) the command line tool to use a remote docker daemon via the environment variable `DOCKER_HOST`. By doing this you can give instructions to docker daemons on remote hosts.

---

There is another point one should mention. When you add a user to a group using `sudo`, and then execute other commands with `sudo`, usually `sudo` will not prompt again for your password, because it is cache for some time.